# Clojure: Simple factorial causes stack overflow

Tags: recursion, clojure, stack-overflow

What am I doing wrong? Simple recursion a few thousand calls deep throws a `StackOverflowError`.

If the limit of Clojure recursions is so low, how can I rely on it?

```
(defn fact[x]
  (if (<= x 1) 1 (* x  (fact (- x 1))  )))

user=> (fact 2)
2

user=> (fact 4)
24

user=> (fact 4000)
java.lang.StackOverflowError (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The stack size, I understand, depends on the JVM you are using as well as the platform. If you are using the Sun JVM, you can use the `-Xss` and `-XThreadStackSize` parameters to set the stack size.

The preferred way to do recursion in Clojure though is to use `loop`/`recur`:

```clj
(defn fact [x]
    (loop [n x f 1]
        (if (= n 1)
            f
            (recur (dec n) (* f n)))))
```

Clojure will do tail-call optimization for this; that ensures that you’ll never run into `StackOverflowError`s.

And due [`defn` implies a `loop` binding](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/flow#__code_defn_code_and_code_recur_code), you could omit the `loop` expression, and use its arguments as the function argument. And to make it a 1 argument function, use [the `multiary` caracteristic of functions](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_multi_arity_functions):

```clj
(defn fact
  ([n] (fact n 1))
  ([n f]
  (if (<= n 1)
    f
    (recur (dec n) (* f n)))))
```

Edit: For the record, here is a Clojure function that returns a lazy sequence of all the factorials:

```clj
(defn factorials []
    (letfn [(factorial-seq [n fact]
                           (lazy-seq
                             (cons fact (factorial-seq (inc n) (* (inc n) fact)))))]
      (factorial-seq 1 1)))

(take 5 (factorials)) ; will return (1 2 6 24 120)
```

Comment: Here's a more elegant way to define an infinite sequence of factorials: `(def facts (lazy-cat [1] (map * facts (iterate inc 2))))`. Then `(take 5 facts)` produces `(1 2 6 24 120)`.

Comment: @android - another way of saying the same thing (since Clojure 1.3): `(def facts (reductions * (iterate inc 1)))`

Comment: `that ensures that you’ll never run into StackOverflowErrors` never? really?

Answer (score 79):

Here's another way:

```
(defn factorial [n]
  (reduce * (range 1 (inc n))))
```

This won't blow the stack because `range` returns a lazy seq, and `reduce` walks across the seq without holding onto the head.

`reduce` makes use of chunked seqs if it can, so this can actually perform better than using `recur` yourself.  Using [Siddhartha Reddy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662336/clojure-simple-factorial-causes-stackoverflow/1662437#1662437) `recur`-based version and this `reduce`-based version:

```
user> (time (do (factorial-recur 20000) nil))
"Elapsed time: 2905.910426 msecs"
nil
user> (time (do (factorial-reduce 20000) nil))
"Elapsed time: 2647.277182 msecs"
nil
```

Just a slight difference.  I like to leave my `recur`ring to `map` and `reduce` and friends, which are more readable and explicit, and use `recur` internally a bit more elegantly than I'm likely to do by hand.  There are times when you need to `recur` manually, but not that many in my experience.

Comment: I completely agree. I think this is a better approach than using loop/recur directly even if the speed difference didn't exist. I would personally use this approach only. I gave the loop/recur version primarily to demonstrate recursion in Clojure.

Comment: I like it was well. BTW, could also be:

`(defn factorial [n]
  (apply * (range 1 (inc n))))`

Comment: In Clojure 1.3.0 I made this work for computing n > 20 by writing
`(defn factorial [n] (reduce *' (range 1 (inc n))))`
Note the ' mark next to the *.

Comment: @MiguelVitorino But is your version head retaining? Imagine your range put inside the arguments of another function.

Answer (score 17):

Clojure has several ways of **busting recursion**

explicit tail calls with **recur**. (they must be truely tail calls so this wont work)

**Lazy sequences** as mentioned above.

**trampolining** where you return a function that does the work instead of doing it directly and then call a trampoline function that repeatedly calls its result until it turnes into a real value instead of a function.

```
(defn fact ([x] (trampoline (fact (dec x) x))) 
           ([x a] (if (<= x 1) a #(fact (dec x) (*' x a)))))
(fact 42)
620448401733239439360000N
```

**memoizing** the the case of fact this can really shorten the stack depth, though it is not generally applicable.

ps: I dont have a repl on me so would someone kindly test-fix the trapoline fact function?

Comment: The function returns an error in REPL, the issue is that a function returned can't be multiplied by preivous function
ClassCastException utilities$fact$fn__16548 cannot be cast to java.lang.Number clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply (Numbers.java:146). My function would be just like @Anon's below `(defn fact ([x] (fact x nil)) ([ x lastResult] (if (<= x 1) (if (nil? lastResult) 1 lastResult) (if (nil? lastResult) (fact (dec x) x) (fact (dec x) (* lastResult x ))) )) )   `  Btw trampoline is called with (trampoline fn arg), so the parenthesis around (fact 42) should be removed

Answer (score 3):

As I was about to post the following, I see that it's almost the same as the Scheme example posted by JasonTrue...  Anyway, here's an implementation in Clojure:

```
user=> (defn fact[x]
        ((fn [n so_far]
          (if (<= n 1)
              so_far
              (recur (dec n) (* so_far n)))) x 1))
#'user/fact
user=> (fact 0)
1
user=> (fact 1)
1
user=> (fact 2)
2
user=> (fact 3)
6
user=> (fact 4)
24
user=> (fact 5)
120
```

etc.

Comment: I can't quite translate it into Clojure yet, so I appreciate that you can, even if nobody else likes my point that continuation passing style is the real solution :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not a Scheme programmer, so I can only speak for this Clojure code, which looked to me to be essentially what your example is doing.  In this, I'm not passing a continuation function, but simply (in an inner "worker" function) the extra accumulator value which gets updated on each call.  My understanding of continuation passing style, just from what I have read, is that all functions take an extra continuation function for what to call next, and that CPS requires tail call optimization to avoid growing the stack, rather than being a work-around to lack of tail call optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The stack depth is a small annoyance (yet configurable), but even in a language with tail recursion like Scheme or F# you'd eventually run out of stack space with your code.

As far as I can tell, your code is unlikely to be tail recursion optimized even in an environment that supports tail recursion transparently. You would want to look at a continuation-passing style to minimize stack depth.

Here's a canonical example in Scheme from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion), which could be translated to Clojure, F# or another functional language without much trouble:

```
(define factorial
  (lambda (n)
      (let fact ([i n] [acc 1])
        (if (zero? i)
            acc
            (fact (- i 1) (* acc i))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

As l0st3d suggested, consider using [recur](http://clojure.org/special%5Fforms#toc10) or [lazy-seq](http://clojure.org/api#lazy-seq).

Also, try to make your sequence lazy by building it using the built-in sequence forms as a opposed to doing it directly.

Here's an example of using the built-in sequence forms to create a lazy Fibonacci sequence (from the Programming Clojure book):

```
(defn fibo []
  (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1])))

=> (take 5 (fibo))
(0 1 1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, simple recursive implementation simple could be this:

```
(defn fac [x]
    "Returns the factorial of x"
    (if-not (zero? x) (* x (fac (- x 1))) 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Siddhartha Reddy's answer, you can also borrow the Factorial function form [Structure And Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%25_sec_1.2.1), with some Clojure-specific tweaks. This gave me pretty good performance even for very large factorial calculations.

```
(defn fac [n]
  ((fn [product counter max-count]
     (if (> counter max-count)
         product
         (recur (apply *' [counter product])
                (inc counter)
                max-count)))
   1 1 n))
```

Answer (score -8):

Factorial numbers are by their nature very big. I'm not sure how Clojure deals with this (but I do see it works with java), but any implementation that does not use big numbers will overflow very fast.

Edit: This is without taking into consideration the fact that you are using recursion for this, which is also likely to use up resources.

Edit x2: If the implementation is using big numbers, which, as far as I know, are usually arrays, coupled with recursion (one big number copy per function entry, always saved on the stack due to the function calls) would explain a stack overflow. Try doing it in a for loop to see if that is the problem.

Comment: Then I would expect to see something like "IntegerOverflow", not "StackOverflow"

Comment: The reason it's a StackOverflow is because your code is essentially making methods calls within method calls until it runs out of stack frames.

Comment: Also, for the record, Clojure has arbitrary precision numerical types.  That means you won't ever get an IntegerOverflow in pure Clojure code.

Comment: There is no reason that the "big integers" would be stored on the stack.  Maybe a reference to them is stored on the stack, but I doubt the entire value is.

Comment: +1 Downvoted and she was right. @cdmckay `;; Clojure 1.5.0-beta2
=> (fact 400)
ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1388)`

Comment: If we use `*'` instead of `*` it does not throw on overflow but dynamically uses needed type.