# What is the difference between these two blocks of Clojure code?

Tags: loops, clojure

While working on the Clojure Koans, I had to calculate the factorial of a number iterativly, I did find the solution, but I have a question about the difference between 2 solutions, one that works and one that doens't, although I don't understand why:

**The one that works:**

```
(defn factorial [n]
   (loop [n n
         acc 1]
     (if (zero? n)
      acc
      (recur (dec n) (* n acc )))
 )
```

**The one that desn't:**

```
(defn factorial [n]
   (loop [n n
         acc 1]
     (if (zero? n)
      1
      (recur (dec n) (* n acc )))
 )
```

Note that the only difference is the returned value of the If block if the condition is met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second `factorial` function always returns `1`. The code is built to use an accumulator variable (`acc`), and the first code block gets it right by returning this accumulator variable.

A `factorial` function can be written to return `1`, though, if an accumulator variable is not used. Since this method does not utilize `loop` / `recur`, it can cause a stack overflow easily: try `(fact 5000)`.

```
(defn factorial [x]
  (if (<= x 1)
      1
      (* x (factorial (- x 1)))))
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662336/clojure-simple-factorial-causes-stack-overflow))

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me :) I was aware of the recursive solution and it's limitations, but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to work out what you think should be happening for the question to make sense.
i think maybe you think `loop` is doing more than it does?  your code is almost equivalent to:

```
(defn factorial 
  ([n] (factorial n 1)
  ([n acc] 
    (if (zero? n)
      acc
      (recur (dec n) (* n acc)))))
```

which is a stack-safe version of

```
(defn factorial 
  ([n] (factorial n 1)
  ([n acc] 
    (if (zero? n)
      acc
      (factorial (dec n) (* n acc)))))
```

so the `acc` (or `1`) is the final value returned from the function.

all that `loop` does is give a different target for `recur`, which is useful if you have some code between the start of the function and the point where you want to repeat.  it's basically a label for a goto.